# Actionscript setTimeout without calling function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In Actionscript, we can do the setTimeout with this:

```
var myboolean:Boolean = false;
var intervalId:uint = setTimeout(changeVariable, 1000); 

public function changeVariable():void { 
    myboolean = true;
}
```

How can do the setTimeout function directly without calling and create a function for simple task as the example above?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at docs and you'll see that `setTimout`' first argument must be `closure:Function` : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function, so you can't just have assignment (or any statement) as first argument.

I believe you can use inline functions as you'd do in JavaScript:

```
var myboolean:Boolean = false;
var intervalId:uint = setTimeout(
     function(){ myboolean = true; }, 1000);
```